Flutter build web, how to generate source-map for packages
When building the app using flutter build web --source-maps the generated source map file doesn't include information about the codes coming from packages. Is there a way to also include package information?

Ensure that the Dart Dev Compiler (DDC) is configured to generate full source maps. This can be done by setting appropriate options in your build.yaml file
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      build_web_compilers|entrypoint:
        options:
          compiler: dartdevc
          dartdevc:
            sourceMaps: true

Create or modify the build.yaml file in your project to include source maps for all packages. This file allows you to customize the build process.
flutter build web --release --source-maps

I tried this but the compiler generated the exact same source map file as before.

Nothing changed with this. Also Warning:  Configuring build_web_compilers:entrypoint in target xxx_app:xxx_app but this is not a known Builder warning printed in the output.
